# Google O-Auth not working in WKWebView

Tags: ios, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am basically working on an iOS app that provides a platform for other web apps to run. These Web apps load in WKWebView of my app. Now, these web apps have Google O-Auth which has stopped working with an error saying useragent_disallowed as google has blocked the use of Web Views. What is the suggested solution?

Comment: Use an `SFSafariViewController` instead.

Comment: The WebView for login is already a Modal. Should I modal SafariController over modal?  How do I know that Google Login Button is Clicked? How do I handle callbacks from SafariController as the owner of web app can be anybody?

Comment: https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html